# Update a mongo collection of 10 billion documents. Without contaminating the data.

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongo of 10 billion documents. Some of which have false information and require updating. The documents look like

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("5567c71e2cdc06be25dbf7a0"),
      "index1" : "stringIndex1",
      "field" : "stringField",
      "index2" : "stringIndex2",
      "value" : 100,
      "unique_id" : "b21fc73e-55a0-4e15-8db0-fa94e4ebcc0b",
      "t" : ISODate("2015-05-29T01:55:39.092Z")
}
```

I want to update the value field for all documents that match criteria on index1, index2 and field. I want to do this across many combinations of the 3 fields.

In an ideal world we could create a second collection and compare the 2 before replacing the original in order to guarantee that we haven't lost any documents. But the size of the collection means that this isn't possible. Any suggestions for how to update this large amount of data without risking damaging it.

Comment: If you're working directly on production data there will **always** be a risk involved. I would recommend exporting several smaller datasets and rigorously testing your script against those before committing to run your changes on the actual data.

Comment: You could also run your script in smaller batches and verify the results after every run. It looks like you might be able to use the timestamp for this and specify date ranges to limit the dataset that is being modified.

Comment: If you want to reduce risk, please use the replication mechanism to make a redundant copy.

Comment: You can do a 2-stage update. First - add a new field e.g. 'fixedValue' with new value to all documents you are going to update. Then check 'update candidates' and amend as needed. On the second stage update the original 'value' from 'fixedValue' and delete the later for all affected documents.

Comment: @tibetty is correct - to properly reduce risk you would need to create a backup in any case... The cost of maintaining a backup (for a limited amount of time) might outweigh the risk of corrupting your only copy of the data.

Comment: @tibetty please note that replication would not help the OP in this case, as any mistake he made would be duly replicated to the other nodes as quickly as possible :) A verified backup and a properly tested algorithm would be the way to go in this case.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha it would be duly replicated to the other nodes as quickly as **configured**: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/replica-set-delayed-member/

Comment: @AlexBlex my point is, please don't conflate replication and backup. You can of course configure delayed secondaries, but it's not a replacement for a verified backup.